# NextJs Image does not show on Safari

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, webp

I am using NextJs for my website. Here is the code I'm using for showing Images

```
      <Image
      src={`/p1.png`}
      layout={"fill"}
      objectFit="contain"
      objectPosition="center"
      alt={"publication image"}
    />
```

This image is visible on all browsers except Safari. How can I make it visible on Safari as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any errors in the dev tool's Network tab related to loading the image? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue fixed. The image container did not have position set as relative

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but wrapping the image component in an element with relative positioning did not fix it... any other leads?

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? Facing the same problem